# Module import fails for unknow reason

Tags: python

Today I tried to make a project where I need to use `import random`, but when I use it, its imports not library but only function random, and I get alert: `NameError: name 'randint' is not defined`.

My code looks like:

```
import random

randomList = []

def randoming() :
    for i in range(8) :
        randomNum = randint(2, 8)
        randomList.append(randomNum)


randoming()

def sixCounter() :
    sixNums = 0
    for a in range(8) :
        if randomList[a] == 6 :
            sixNums = sixNums + 1
    print(f"In that list are {sixNums} six numbers")


print("The numbers in list are:")
print(*randomList, sep = ", ")
sixCounter()
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and write your code in ```Your Code``` to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, my first question, it looks good now?

Comment: The import line you wrote works fine. Can you explain where `randint` is being defined in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**
When you import any module as following,

```
import module
```

to call any function from the module, you have to do it as an **attribute of the module**. Like this:

```
module.function()
```

Calling *only* the function will raise an undefinition error.

**THE SOLUTION**
To solve your problem, call the randint function like this:

```
random.randint()
```

**OR** import the module like this

```
from random import *
```

This instruction will "move" all the functions of the module random to your code, so that you don't have to call any function as an attribute of the module.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to reference randint as random.randin or import randint from random

i.e. either:

```
from random import randint

randomList = []

def randoming() :
    for i in range(8) :
        randomNum = randint(2, 8)
        randomList.append(randomNum)


randoming()

def sixCounter() :
    sixNums = 0
    for a in range(8) :
        if randomList[a] == 6 :
            sixNums = sixNums + 1
    print(f"In that list are {sixNums} six numbers")


print("The numbers in list are:")
print(*randomList, sep = ", ")
sixCounter()
```

or

```
import random

randomList = []

def randoming() :
    for i in range(8) :
        randomNum = random.randint(2, 8)
        randomList.append(randomNum)


randoming()

def sixCounter() :
    sixNums = 0
    for a in range(8) :
        if randomList[a] == 6 :
            sixNums = sixNums + 1
    print(f"In that list are {sixNums} six numbers")


print("The numbers in list are:")
print(*randomList, sep = ", ")
sixCounter()
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helped, but I am too want know why `import random` don't import full random library, but only method random

Comment: When you call randint, the python interpreter will look for that function, but it is defined inside of the module random. When you import the module random that module is available, but randint is only available from within random. Hence, either specifically import randint from random or call it from the parent module (random.randint)